# how to add favicon to pdf in tcpdf library for my codeigniter project?

Tags: codeigniter, pdf, tcpdf, favicon

In my codeigniter application there are some pdf's. I used tcpdf to generate these pdf's, now i want to put favicon in these pdf's need suggestion.

Comment: Do you have the favicon.ico file in your web root folder?

Comment: yes i had favicon.ico

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally i found the solution. We need to add favicon.ico to root directory of application, pdf's will automatically use this favicon.